# build apks with different app name and logo from one project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on an Android Project in which I have many clients who will be using my app. And the number of clients may increase . I want to use my **same project and build different APK with their own logo and app name**. I dont want to change anything else.
   
Basically I want to change the App name string (Wherever i have used it in my project to show app name)
Same for the image. (I am using same image for displaying the notification icon so that also should update).
I dont have any deep knowledge about the gradle.
I am using Android Studio with gradle.

How shall i go about to implement this. And how will i use it?
Yeah and if more info is needed to answer this question Please tell me what info is needed and why.
And good quick starter link would also be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different build variants (custom ones, in addition to the default `debug` and `release`).  Within those build variants' `res` directories, you can provide alternative drawables and string resources. Also, you can designate a new `applicationIdSuffix` in gradle, so that there will be a unique Application ID for the play store.

```
...
buildTypes {
    clientA {
        applicationIdSuffix ".clientA"
    }

    clientB {
        applicationIdSuffix ".clientB"
    }

    ...
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks bro! Saved me big time. Tomorrow is my deadline and this thing was only left. Got it.